# マルチソケット環境(複数CPUがある環境)のDockerプロセスの使い方(均等化)について。

Tags: docker

【問題点】
マルチソケット環境（1つのサーバーにCPUが2つ載っている環境）にてDockerプロセスを動かすと片方のCPUにしかリソースが使われていない傾向が見られます。

この偏りを無くしたいのですが、どのような方法があるかご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらアドバイス頂けませんでしょうか？

・Docker側（プロセス側）に視点を向けた場合の方法
[マルチソケット環境向けに最適化された起動オプションがある等]

・ホスト側（サーバー側）に視点を向けた場合の方法
[サーバー上の全て（又は特定の）プロセスをマルチソケット環境向けに最適化するような設定等]

その他 etc

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: ホストの OS によって、挙動がかなり変わるかもしれません。お使いのホストOS は何でしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。情報不足で申し訳ございません。CentOS7.2となります。

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1153193 こちらの記事にそれらしいことが書いてありそうな気がするのですが、見れないのです；

Comment: RedHatのページは、Red Hat アカウントでログインしないと読めません。Red Hat アカウントを持っていないなら、アカウントを作ってから、ログインしてみてください。

Comment: SUBSCRIBER EXCLUSIVE CONTENTと表示yされてアカウントを作成しても見れないのです。もしかしたら有料契約？みたいなのをしないと見れないページかもしれません；

Answer (score 1):

Multiple CPUs can be specified. This command will assign the mycontainer Docker Container to CPU 0 and 1:
Raw
`# docker run --cpuset 0,1 /bin/bash mycontainer`

Docker側（プロセス側）に視点を向けた場合の方法としては上記でいけそうです。

引き続き
ホスト側（サーバー側）に視点を向けた場合の方法
[サーバー上の全て（又は特定の）プロセスをマルチソケット環境向けに最適化するような設定等]
こちらの情報などございましたら教えて頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: [tasksetコマンド](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-JP/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Affinity.html)や[numactlコマンド](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-JP/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/main-cpu.html)のような機能でしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。リンクページありがとうございます。大変わかりやすいです。このようなことをやりたいのです。もう少し詳しく調べてみます。ありがとうございます！